# How should stale indexes be handled during testing?

Tags: c#, testing, ravendb, indexing

I am using RavenDB in In-Memory mode for unit testing. My queries are backed by static indexes. I am not using `WaitForNonStaleResults()` API (nor do I want to).

Typical workflow for a test is:

1. Initialise RavenDB in In-Memory mode
2. Integrate indexes using `IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(Assembly, IDocumentStore)`
3. Insert test data (for verifying  query behaviour)
4. Run query
5. Verify query output

I have noticed steps 1-3 happen so quickly, that static indexes don't have time to get updated before step 4 - therefore the indexes are stale.

I have created a quick work-around for this. After step 3, I execute:

```
while (documentStore.DocumentDatabase.Statistics.StaleIndexes.Length != 0)
    Thread.Sleep(10);
```

This feels cumbersome. What I would like to know is:

- Is it normal for indexes to be stale when running RavenDB in In-Memory mode?
- Is there a better way to avoid stale indexes during testing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cross-posted this to [RavenDB usergroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ravendb) and have a working solution.

> Is it normal for indexes to be stale when running RavenDB in In-Memory
>   mode?

Yes. An index is an index.

> Is there a better way to avoid stale indexes during testing?

Yes. Configure global conventions when initialising document store:

```
var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore();
store.RunInMemory = true;
store.Conventions = new DocumentConvention
{
    DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites
};

store.Initialize();
```

**Note:** `ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites` doesn't work with Map/Reduce indexes, i.e. indexes with a `Reduce => ...` section. For these you have to use `Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStale...())` when querying

**Update:** There is [another approach](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/W5QSqENrE5E/bJN-F-IFQPkJ), which may be better (haven't personally tried it yet). You could implement IDocumentQueryListener to force all queries to return non-stale results:

```
var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { RunInMemory = true };
store.Initialize();

store.RegisterListener(new ForceNonStaleQueryListener());

public class ForceNonStaleQueryListener : IDocumentQueryListener
{
    public void BeforeQueryExecuted(IDocumentQueryCustomization customization)
    {
        queryCustomization.WaitForNonStaleResults();
    }
}
```

Comment: @MattWarren Thanks, Matt. Useful to know.

Comment: The Listener approach is no longer valid with the current RavenDB builds.

Comment: @FerretallicA I will check this again with the latest build.

Comment: @FerretallicA Just checked against build #2025 - seems to work just fine. Was it a particular build that didn't work?

Comment: Ignore last comment. This functionality is not available in the current stable build.

Comment: Did anyone found any good solution for last build? What I am doing now - is just defining a property of type RavenQueryable<T> in testing class to wrap session.Query<T>().Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults())