# How does RavenDb "In" operator work?

Tags: c#, linq, lucene, ravendb

I probably don't understand how the "In" extension method in RavenDb works. I thought that it is an equivalent of the IN command in SQL world, e.g. WHERE Number IN (1, 2, 3). But it behaves quite weird.

```
// i have 3 records - two with Normal severity, one with Low severity
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    session.Store(new TestObject { Name = "o1", Severity = Severity.Normal });
    session.Store(new TestObject { Name = "o2", Severity = Severity.Low });
    session.Store(new TestObject { Name = "o3", Severity = Severity.Normal });
    session.SaveChanges();
}

// this writes the Low severity record, it seems correct
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    var data = session.Query<TestObject>()
        .Where(o => o.Severity.In(new[] { Severity.Low }))
        .OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
    data.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r));
}

// this writes also the Low severity record, it still seems correct
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    var data = session.Query<TestObject>()
        .Where(o => o.Severity.In(new[] { Severity.Low, Severity.High }))
        .OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
    data.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r));
}

// this writes all records, still seems correct
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    var data = session.Query<TestObject>()
        .Where(o => o.Severity.In(
            new[] { Severity.High, Severity.Low, Severity.Normal }))
        .OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
    data.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r));
}

// but this does not write anything 
// despite there are 2 records with Normal severity
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    var data = session.Query<TestObject>()
        .Where(o => o.Severity.In(new[] { Severity.High, Severity.Normal }))
        .OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
    data.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r));
}

// and this does not write anything either, 
// I just tried whether the order of values in the array matters
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    var data = session.Query<TestObject>()
        .Where(o => o.Severity.In(new[] { Severity.Normal, Severity.High }))
        .OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
    data.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r));
}
```

Or did I find a bug in the RavenDb/Lucene engine?

### Edit

I have found another strange thing. It has to do something with the alphabetical order of enum members. When I rename the Severity.Normal to Severity.A, the last two queries behave correctly and return the results. 
When I rename the Severity.Normal to Severity.La, it still works (because La < Low). But when I rename the Severity.Normal to Severity.Lu (Lu > Low), it breaks and the last two queries are not returning results any more. The original sample does not work because Normal > Low. But I still wonder why it happens because it makes no sense to me.

Comment: what version of RavenDb are you using?

Comment: I use the latest build 2159.

Comment: I have tested with builds 960 (stable) and 2159, 2160 (unstable) and could not reproduce the error. For me it worked fine even without the `WaitForNonStaleResults` option. Do you have any Bundles activated or any unusual settings? Does this happen every time you run the code or just occasionally?

Comment: Happens to me every time. No bundles, no special settings.

Comment: Another idea: **1.** Run the code that stores the items; **2.** Inspect the documents in the DB with RavenDb Management Studio - see if they look like you'd expect; **3.** run the queries only to see if you get the weird results again. This should avoid any stale index issues.

Comment: I have tried this, the RavenDB Management Studio shows that 0 indexes are stale. When I run those quesies, it behaves always the same.
I don't think it is stale index issue. I'll try to reproduce the issue on another machine.

Comment: OK, indexes are not stale. Have you also checked the contents of the documents?

Comment: Yes, the documents are OK. I also tried to do the query directly in the RavenDB Management Studio and it behaves the same as the C# app. However I am unable to reproduce it on another computer.

Answer (score 6):

You are running into stale indexes, which is why you get strange results.
You need to wait for the indexing to complete first.

Comment: Strange. I have set 
    store.Conventions.DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites;
previously and even if I add 
    .Customize(a => a.WaitForNonStaleResults())
    it behaves the same.

Comment: The `DefaultQueryingConsistency` feature did not work for me either. I have written an extension method that helps. See RavenDb : [Force indexes to wait until not stale whilst unit testing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10316721/776476)

Comment: To all future readers, make sure you don't use the solution from  @biofractal in any location other than a unit test.