# Possible bug in RavenDB EmbeddableDocumentStore

Tags: linq, ravendb

We are in the process of upgrading to RavenDB 2.5 and have run into a peculiar situation.
One of our unit tests is suddenly failing, and for no obvious reason.

Here is some simple code to reproduce the issue:

```
class Foo
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? ExpirationTime { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        ExpirationTime = null;
    }
}

var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
    {
        RunInMemory = true,
        Conventions = { DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites }
    };
documentStore.Initialize();

using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    session.Store(new Foo());
    session.Store(new Foo());
    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

So, now we have two documents in the database, both with ExpirationTime = null.
This is what happens when querying the database for these documents:

```
using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    var bar = session.Query<Foo>().Where(foo => foo.ExpirationTime == null).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("1. Number of documents: {0}", bar.Count);

    bar = session.Query<Foo>().Where(foo => foo.ExpirationTime == null || 
                                     foo.ExpirationTime > DateTime.Now).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("2. Number of documents: {0}", bar.Count);

    bar = session.Query<Foo>().Where(foo => foo.ExpirationTime == null | 
                                     foo.ExpirationTime > DateTime.Now).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("3. Number of documents: {0}", bar.Count);        
}
```

The output from these queries are as follows:

```
1. Number of documents: 2
2. Number of documents: 0
3. Number of documents: 2
```

This doesn't seem correct to me... I would expect also number 2. to give 2.

I ran the same queries against a RavenDB server, and got the expected results, so it seems like this is an issue with the EmbeddableDocumentStore.

While testing this I also found some strange behavior when using the logical or operator in other cases. Sometimes using `foo.HasValue` would give different result than `foo != null`, but that might be related to the same issue.

Anyone else that have experienced this problem? Known bug?

Comment: [RavenDb : Force indexes to wait until not stale whilst unit testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316721/ravendb-force-indexes-to-wait-until-not-stale-whilst-unit-testing)

Could it be something with a `stale index`?

Comment: @NoLifeKing I was not showing it in the example code, bu I always use either `DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites` or `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite()` when unit testing. Also this did work as expected before upgrading to Raven 2.5.

Comment: Please send a failing unit test to the mailing list

Comment: @AyendeRahien I just did :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in RavenDB related to sorting on null fields.
Fixed in the next build